# What is the matter with if statement in procedure?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, procedure

It is simple to write a sql procedure.

```
demiliter //
create procedure show_growth()
begin
SELECT * from tb;
end //
```

I want to add a if statement in the procedure.
Drop it first.

```
 drop procedure show_growth //
```

Then create a new one.

```
create procedure show_growth(in type char(3))
    -> begin
    -> if type = "all" then 
    -> SELECT * from tb;
    -> endif
    -> end //
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 6

How to fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mariadb, but I think it's a missing `;` after the endif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`endif` is not 1 word.

```
 begin
   if type = "all" then    
    SELECT * from tb;
   end if;
 end
```